# Making multiple persistent HTTP connections between functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-requests

There's a website I would like to login to on two different accounts and create two separate persistent HTTP connections. The only way I know how to do this is to have a separate login function twice but that would seem kind of redundant so I just made the function login(). But now I would like to somehow re-use the same login function to create multiple persistent HTTP sessions in my other functions but it goes out of scope.

```
def login(username, password):
    requests.post('example.com', data=payload)

def website1():
    login("matthew", "qwerty")
    session = requests.session()

def website2():
    login("matthew2", "qwerty2")
    session = requests.session()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use requests cookie jar which support multiple domains :

```
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()

def login(url, domain, username, password):
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    jar.set('session', r.cookies['session'], domain=domain) # assuming its name is session
```

And then for using the session cookie on both sites :

```
requests.get(url, cookies=jar)
```

For more information :

- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies
- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar